# Is there a dilated k-nearest neighbour solution available fast execution?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I am implementing the `dilated k-nearest neighbors algorithm`. The algorithm unfortunately has nested loops. The presence of loops severely hampers the execution speed.

```
import torch
dilation=3
nbd_size=5
knn_key=torch.randint([0,30,(64,12,198,100)])


dilated_keys=torch.zeros([knn_key.shape[0],knn_key.shape[1],knn_key.shape[2],nbd_size])

for i in range(knn_key.shape[0]):
    for j in range(knn_key.shape[1]):
        for k in range(knn_key.shape[2]):
            list_indices=[]
            while (len(list_indices))<nbd_size:
                for l in range(knn_key.shape[3]):
                    if knn_key[i][j][k][l]%dilation==k%dilation:
                        list_indices.append(knn_key[i][j][k][l])
                        if (len(list_indices))>=nbd_size:
                            break
            list_indices_tensor=torch.tensor(list_indices)
            dilated_keys[i][j][k]=list_indices_tensor
```

The variable `knn_key` stores the `100` nearest neighbours among the 1000 data points originally available. The `dilated_keys` stores the `nbd_size=5` selected indices of the neighbours that are used after applying dialation filter. Any help to use broadcasting solution to remove the three nested loops will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the inner loops and conditions as follows:

```
import torch

dilation = 3
nbd_size = 5
knn_key = torch.randint(0, 30, (64, 12, 198, 100))

dilated_keys = torch.zeros((knn_key.shape[0], knn_key.shape[1], knn_key.shape[2], nbd_size), dtype=torch.int64)

for i in range(knn_key.shape[0]):
    for j in range(knn_key.shape[1]):
        for k in range(knn_key.shape[2]):
            key = knn_key[i, j, k]
            indices = torch.nonzero(key % dilation == k % dilation).squeeze()
            selected_indices = indices[:nbd_size]
            dilated_keys[i, j, k] = key[selected_indices]
```